# Spring Data JPA Native Query - How to use Postgres ARRAY type as a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a native postgresql query (opts - jsonb array):

```sql
select * from table users jsonb_exists_any(opts, ARRAY['CASH', 'CARD']);
```

it works fine in my database console and I'm getting a result:

```
user1, ['CASH','CARD']
user2, ['CASH']
user3, ['CARD']
```

but when I want to use it in my spring data jpa application as:

```java
@Query(value = "select * from users where jsonb_exists_any(opts, ARRAY[?1])", nativeQuery = true)
List<Users> findUsers(Set<String> opts);
```

I'm getting an error:

> h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
> h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: function jsonb_exists_any(jsonb,
> record[]) does not exist

because that query converts to:

```sql
select
    * 
from
    users 
where
    jsonb_exists_any(opts, ARRAY[(?, ?)])
```

Is there a way to pass parameters as an array? i.e. without brackets around `?, ?`

Comment: You were able to solve it?

Comment: @damike I haven't found nothing better than soung's answer

Comment: I found a solution yesterday:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrap_varchar(VARIADIC params VARCHAR[])
RETURNS SETOF VARCHAR[]
AS $$
  SELECT params;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;`
Then
`SELECT jsonb_exists_any('{"name": "Joe Smith", "age": 28, "sports": ["football"]}', wrap_varchar('age','address'));` which works with spring data. You can replace `'age','address'` with `:filter`

Answer (score 6):

can you try this :

```
@Query(value = "select * from users where jsonb_exists_any(opts, string_to_array(?1, ','))", nativeQuery = true)
List<Users> findUsers(String listStringSeparatedByComma);
```

Notice you have to replace the Set parameter by a String.

Comment: yeah, your solution works, but I'm curious if there is an option to somehow use a list or array without converting and joining values to a string

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
@Query(value = "with array_query as (select array_agg(value) as array_value from (select (json_each_text(row_to_json(row_values))).value from (values ?1) row_values) col_values)"+
" select * from users where jsonb_exists_any(opts, (select array_value from array_query))", nativeQuery = true)
List<Users> findUsers(Set<String> opts);
```